# Slow MySQL queries, how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, default-settings

I worked on some project with more than 30M columns. Some requests take too much time on my local machine (SSD, i5-8300, 16GB memory) and I think it is because I set up my PHP/MySQL incorrectly.

My colleges work with MAMP,and don't have this problem but some MAMP settings are custom and named like `MAMP_SOME_SETTING = MAMP_SOME_VAL`, so i can't easily integrate them into my settings.

How can I get all the working settings from one MySQL client and setup it up on other device?

Comment: What does that "MAMP" have to do with it? Do the same queries run fast for them or are they simply not doing those kind of queries? Did you watch out for CPU/Memory/HDD utilization? Did you check your logs?

Comment: @Seth yes. On the same code base they do same requests. I asked my another colleg, he said that he just install base mysql, and all works fine. Now i dont understand, what is really happens with my machine

Comment: Do they have the same hardware? Do they use the same software? Do they have the same anti virus solution? Have those queries always been slow for you or was it a recent change? There are so many variables to this that it's hard to come to a conclusion based on the what you've said so far. It's unclear what queries you're running, what you deem slow and what you have tried. Analyzing the query and figuring out what makes it slow might be a better approach.

Comment: Why aren't you using the same software configuration and setup as your colleagues?

Comment: When I read "30M columns" I nearly had a heart attack. Did you mean 30M rows?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.